# Getting "Does not point to a valid commit"

Tags: github

I'm trying to rebase my branch onto a remote master, and I'm getting this message, any idea what this means?

```
git clone https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
git checkout macbook

git remote add tfmain https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
git fetch -a 

git rebase --onto tfmain/master

fatal: Needed a single revision
Does not point to a valid commit: tfmain/master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably meant

```
git fetch --all
```

Comment: Also switch to the branch after fetching to create it locally

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
git fetch remote_name     #to get all the branches
```

Second in the desktop git:

```
git config pull.rebase true
git rebase --onto=your_aid_branch
git push remote_name  -u
```